# Class ShopgateConfig not found - magento

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.9

I have installed a custom module in my Magento website but now, when I try to reach the frontend of my website I receive an error. Class 'ShopgateConfig' not found.

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'ShopgateConfig' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blugento\\.modman\\shopgate_magento_integration\\src\\app\\code\\community\\Shopgate\\Framework\\Model\\Config.php on line 42, referer: blugento.local/index.php/admin/system_config/index/key/....
```

But the class exists because I found it in one of the module files. This is the code where the class is called:

```
class Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config extends ShopgateConfig{...}
```

And there is the implementatin of the class:

```
class ShopgateConfig extends ShopgateContainer implements ShopgateConfigInterface{...}
```

Which could be the problem? Do I have to change something in the config.xml file or somewhere to find my class?

If is necessary I'll post more of my code if you'll tell me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do do refresh the cache ?

Do you see the module enabled in your configuration (system > configuration > advanced > Advanced) ?

What is the exact error you get in your log ?

Comment: I refreshed the cache tens of times but nothing changed. The module is enabled in configuration. The error from log is "[Thu Dec 14 16:05:12.357699 2017] [php7:error] [pid 10764:tid 1940] [client 127.0.0.1:57922] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ShopgateConfig' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blugento\\.modman\\shopgate_magento_integration\\src\\app\\code\\community\\Shopgate\\Framework\\Model\\Config.php on line 42, referer: http://blugento.local/index.php/admin/system_config/index/key/5a692a9898ad9b155ac9404163f4bf95/"

Answer (score 0):

Well you are on M1 so you need to confirm ShopgateConfig class is on right directory. Magento will show that error when they don't find right path for ShopgateConfig.php file

Can you tell me path of ShopgateConfig file? And from below syntax

> class Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config extends ShopgateConfig

I assume if you are calling this file then it must be inside lib folder

Comment: Yes, the file is in /lib/Shopgate/cart-integration-sdk/src/configuration.php

Comment: Have you tried to include that file using 

require_once 'shopgate-cart-integration-sdk/shopgate.php'; 

I checked your api from here 
https://github.com/shopgate/cart-integration-sdk

I saw it doesnt have autoload file inside it so its not loading any class for api